# new info window does not work when i click on google map marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hello i am having problem to show new infowindow when i click on marker.I want to show infowindow after click on marker. Please someone one give me a solution. My code is given bellow.

```
var markerClusterer = null;

var map = null;

function refreshMap() {

    if (markerClusterer) {
      markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    }

    var markers = [];
     var style = parseInt(document.getElementById('style').value, 10);      
    if (style == 0) {           
        var data =w_plaza;
        var imageUrl = 'images/walton.png';
    }
    if (style == 1) {           
        var data =w_dealer;
        var imageUrl = 'images/people35.png';
    }
    if (style == 2) {           
        var data =w_service_center;
        var imageUrl = 'images/service_center.png';
    }

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl);
      //  var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
      //new google.maps.Size(24, 32));



      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var loc = data[i];
      var latLng =  new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1],loc[2]);
      var content = loc[0] + ":" + loc[1] + "," + loc[2];          
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latLng,
       draggable: true,
       icon: markerImage
      });   

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent("hello");
      infowindow.open(map, marker);          
    });

      markers.push(marker);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time we see `infowindow` in your code is at:

```
infowindow.setContent("hello");
```

What is infowindow, where was it created?  Nowhere as far as I can see.  Somewhere in your function, before we get as far as creating the marker, create it something like this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```